# ¿Cómo calcular SentimentIntensityAnalyzer en un dataframe de tabla de texto?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nlp, nltk

Tengo una dataframe con dos columnas. Una de ellas esta las fechas, la otra es articulos.

```
Date
2017-10-20    [Gucci debuts art installation at its Ginza st...
2017-12-07    [GUCCI opens new store at Miami Design Distric...
2018-01-12       [Gucci opens Gucci Garden in Florence - LUXUO]
2018-02-26    [GUCCI's wild experiment with the Fall Winter ...
2018-04-20    [Gucci launches its new creative hub Gucci Art...
2018-08-01    [Gucci Joins Paris Fashion Week for Its Spring...
2018-08-09    [Gucci Revamped London Flagship Store | The Im...
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Me gustaría calcular sobre la dataframe puntuaciones de sentimiento de NLTK. Entonces hice :

```
# Adding new columns to the data frame
df_news["compound"] = ''
df_news["neg"] = ''
df_news["neu"] = ''
df_news["pos"] = ''
```

Para añadir columnas y intente el siguiente código :

```
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
import unicodedata
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
for date, row in df_news.T.iteritems():
    try:
        sentence = df_news.loc[date, 'name']
        ss = sid.polarity_scores(str(sentence))
        df_news.set_value(date, 'compound', ss['compound'])
        df_news.set_value(date, 'neg', ss['neg'])
        df_news.set_value(date, 'neu', ss['neu'])
        df_news.set_value(date, 'pos', ss['pos'])
    except TypeError:
        print("We have a TypeError")
        print(df_news.loc[date, 'name'])
        print(date)
```

Me dio `TypeError` antes.

## Actualización

No sé cómo pero resolví el error y parecía que funciona.

```
    Date    name    compound    neg neu pos
0   2017-10-20  [Gucci debuts art installation at its Ginza st...   0   0   1   0
1   2017-12-07  [GUCCI opens new store at Miami Design Distric...   0   0   1   0
2   2018-01-11  [GUCCI launches fine dining restaurant - CPP-L...   0.2023  0   0.735   0.265
3   2018-01-12  [Gucci opens Gucci Garden in Florence - LUXUO]  0   0   1   0
4   2018-02-26  [GUCCI's wild experiment with the Fall Winter ...   0   0   1   0
5   2018-04-20  [Gucci launches its new creative hub Gucci Art...   0.4404  0   0.756   0.244
6   2018-08-01  [Gucci Joins Paris Fashion Week for Its Spring...   0   0   1   0
7   2018-08-09  [Gucci Revamped London Flagship Store | The Im...   0.1027  0   0.811   0.189
```

Sin embargo, para algunas líneas, parece que él da opiniones muy neutrales, mientras que realmente podría tomar ventaja. Por ejemplo :

```
2018-02-26  [GUCCI's wild experiment with the Fall Winter ...   0   0   1   0
```

Por otra parte parece que da opiniones desfasados :

Tenemos *wild* que significa salvaje en castellano. Debería haber dado un verdadero positivo. Pero solo da un neutral = 1.

Intente inicializar el dataframe con `int` más bien que `str` `''`:

```
# Añadiendo nuevas columnas al marco de datos.
df_news["compound"] = 0
df_news["neg"] = 0
df_news["neu"] = 0
df_news["pos"] = 0
```

Pero me da el siguiente :

```
    Date        name                                           compound neg neu pos
0   2017-10-20  [Gucci debuts art installation at its Ginza st...   0   0   1   0
1   2017-12-07  [GUCCI opens new store at Miami Design Distric...   0   0   1   0
2   2018-01-11  [GUCCI launches fine dining restaurant - CPP-L...   0   0   0   0
3   2018-01-12  [Gucci opens Gucci Garden in Florence - LUXUO]  0   0   1   0
4   2018-02-26  [GUCCI's wild experiment with the Fall Winter ...   0   0   1   0
5   2018-04-20  [Gucci launches its new creative hub Gucci Art...   0   0   0   0
6   2018-08-01  [Gucci Joins Paris Fashion Week for Its Spring...   0   0   1   0
7   2018-08-09  [Gucci Revamped London Flagship Store | The Im...   0   0   0   0
```

Y no resolvía las problemas.

Comment: ThePassenger, no conozco Pandas, pero me parece que el hecho de que **df_news["compound"]**, sea inicializado con '', es decir, sea un dato de tipo cadena, mientras que el resultado de **polarity** sea decimal, es el motivo del error de tipo.

Comment: @RodrigoN Resolvi el error, no me recuerdo como. Sin embargo estoy desengañado con los resultados ... Probé lo que has sugerido y actualicé la pregunta.

Comment: No parece que la puntuación neutral de la frase tenga nada qué ver con Pandas o con los tipos de las columnas. Si no quieres inicializarlas con cadenas vacías puedes hacerlo con `0.0` (para que sean flotantes en vez de enteros), pero la puntuación del analizador de sentimientos es independiente eso, como puedes comprobar dándole directamente la frase con `sid.polarity_scores('GUCCI’s wild experiment with the Fall Winter 2018 catwalk show')`, y verás que da lo mismo. Quizás necesites probar otros analizadores.